# How to change file extensions of multiple files in XP?

Tags: windows-xp

XP lets you rename files in bulk by simply selecting multiple files within Windows Explorer and pressing the <kbd>F2</kbd> key. When you use this feature, the OS applies the name you enter to the first file and applies the same name with a number in parentheses to the other files you selected (the file extensions remain unchanged).

For example, if you select the following files,

- `notes.doc`
- `figures.xls`
- `disney.jpg`
- `holiday.gif`

and rename the first file (`notes.doc`) to `SoD.doc`, XP renames the remaining files as follows:

- `SoD (1).xls`
- `SoD (2).jpg`
- `SoD (3).gif`

How do I change the extension of these multiple files at once.

Comment: `C:\folder\> ren *.* *.newextension`?

Comment: @ techie007 : Great..Its working. Thank you.

Comment: It was more of a question than a suggestion. ;)  I'll stick it in as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the command line interface and use the rename function:

`C:\folder\> ren *.* *.newextension`

This will rename everything to ".newextension".

Answer (score 3):

You could use **[Massive File Renamer](https://ivanrf.com/en/portfolio-posts/massive-file-renamer/)**

It will allow you to easily **rename multiple file extensions**. It's very fast and simple!

For advanced users and developers, it is possible to use **regular expressions**.
See it in action:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible natively but for my needs, I use a tool called [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php), I know it seems like an overkill (not to mention the UI) at first but it's worth it :

[image: Bulk Rename Utility main windows]

Comment: Whoever "designed" that interface should be taken out into the public square and flogged.